# HTTP Response Query

Tags: java, http, url-rewriting

The query I have has something do with an implementation I`m doing.

When a HTTP request is sent from the client Port to the Server Port, I understand that 
the response is also sent back to the same port(Port to Port communication).

In my case, the server is forwarding the response to a URL with Query String to a host server on our network. So what I get when reading the response using the InputStream of the URLConnection object is the HTML content corresponding to the Login page of the forwarded URL with no query string.

I suspect this is because the URL is modified by our host server.

Now the question is, in this scenario there seems to be an intermediate entity which is the our host server to which URL is forwarded. So, when I read the response(URL forwarded by server) back in the InputStream, I`m not sure which of the following 2 is the actual scenario happening:

1.) Response is directly read from the external Server(as this is a Port to Port communication)

OR

2.)Response received from the intermediate Host Server which sees to be the case.

(If the 2nd scenario is correct, would the intermediate host server know which client to correctly forward the response to?)

```
URL url = new URL(httpsURL);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true); 
///
Omitting code for SSL
///
String urlParameters = "CCNumber=4111111111111111";
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(inputLine);
 }
}
```

Comment: Show us your client code.

Comment: Attached the client code..The response is nothing but the HTML page content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the response from the intermediate server.

It sounds like your intermediate server acts as a ([reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Reverse_proxies)) [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). When you make a request to your intermediate server, it in turn makes a request to the server on your network (just as you described it). However, the "real" server has usually no idea that the request was initiated by you. In particular, it does not know your IP address or the port you sent your request from. The only thing it *does* know is the IP address and port of the intermediate (the proxy) server. The proxy server on the other hand still knows the IP address and port from which you sent your request.

So you send your request to the proxy, the proxy sends it to the "real" server, the real server sends its response back to the proxy, which sends it back to you. You and the "real" server do not communicate directly with each other.

Comment: The answer was helpful but I couldn't vote it up for lack of enough reputation.I have 1 question. After getting the i/p stream, I invoked the getURL() method to find out the redirected URL to find out thequery String they sent. But, it seems the URL that I`m getting is the one that my intermediate Server sends b'coz it appends the main URL with session id info. Is there any way to find out what was the original URL sent by the server. Do I need to put up a filter on the intermediate server to intercept the incoming url pattern so I can get access to the query string sent by the ext. Server.

Comment: Invoking `getUrl()` only returns the URL that you created the `URLConnection` with (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getURL%28%29)).  
You _cannot_ find out the URL that the proxy server requested from the "real" server. But that's exactly the point of the proxy. For all you know from the client's perspective, the proxy server _is_ the real server...